# XSD schema for this fragment

Tags: xml, xsd

i'm writing a schema, and i can't think of how to represent this xml fragment:

```
<ActionTaken>
   <Description partID="H1" sequenceNumber="01">i did this</Description>
   <Description partID="H1" sequenceNumber="02">and then some more stuff.</Description>
</ActionTaken>
```

What i had initially created was:

```
<xs:element name="ActionTaken">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="Description" type="String400" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="99" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="partID" type="STReportTypeEnum" />
      <xs:attribute name="partSequenceNumber" type="NumericTwoRJZ" />
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

But that's wrong because the attributes are applied to the `ActionTaken` element, rather than the `Description` elements.

> **Note**: Is there ***ANY*** way to declare attributes before the elements? Attributes do, after all, come **before** elements!

So i'm trying to figure out how to push the attributes down onto the `Description` element:

```
<xs:element name="ActionTaken">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Description" type="String400" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="99" />
            <xs:attribute name="partID" type="STReportTypeEnum" />
            <xs:attribute name="partSequenceNumber" type="NumericTwoRJZ" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

That doesn't work because you cannot have an `attribute` in the `sequence`. i tried:

```
<xs:element name="ActionTaken">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Description" type="String400" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="99" >
                <xs:attribute name="partID" type="STReportTypeEnum" />
                <xs:attribute name="partSequenceNumber" type="NumericTwoRJZ" />
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But that doesn't work because of who the hell knows.

i could keep randomly trying s<strike>h</strike>tuff; or i could get the real answer.

---

### Attempt 4

```
<xs:element name="ActionTaken">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Description" type="String400" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="99" >
                <xs:attribute name="partID" type="STReportTypeEnum" />
                <xs:attribute name="partSequenceNumber" type="NumericTwoRJZ" />
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

### Attempt 5

```
<xs:element name="DescriptionOfSuspiciousActivity">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Description" type="String400" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="99">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <!--Description of Suspicious Activity (Part G) attributes-->
                    <xs:attribute name="partID" type="STReportTypeEnum" />
                    <xs:attribute name="partSequenceNumber" type="NumericTwoRJZ" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

### Attempt 6

```
<xs:element name="ActionTaken">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Description" type="String400" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="99" >
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="partID" type="STReportTypeEnum" />
                    <xs:attribute name="partSequenceNumber" type="NumericTwoRJZ" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Camel: a horse designed by committee
XSD: designed by committee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i could keep randomly trying s<strike>h</strike>tuff; or i could get the real answer.

I suggest checking out the [W3Schools XSD tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp).

What you want to do is define the attributes inside the element which is defined as a complex type:

```
<xs:element name="ActionTaken"> 
  <xs:complexType> 
    <xs:sequence> 
      <xs:element name="Description" 
        type="DescriptionString400" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="99"
      />
    </xs:sequence> 
  </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element> 
<xs:complexType name="DescriptionString400">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="String400">
      <xs:attribute name="partID" type="STReportTypeEnum" /> 
      <xs:attribute name="partSequenceNumber" type="NumericTwoRJZ" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: `The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType`. Which makes sense, it's not a complex type - it's just a type with attributes.

Comment: i've been going over W3Schools extensively - they fall quite short in a large number of areas.

Comment: @Ian: Then define an extension of type "String400" with attributes and define "Description"'s type as that new type.

Comment: Could i get an example of such a thing? In this case String400 is `xs:string` with `xs:maxlength = 400` i ask because i can't figure it out in-place; and it's the same syntax - so i can't figure it out.

Comment: @Ian: Updated my post. You can't have a `complexType` and a `type` at the same time. You have to define one as an extension of the other and use the extended type.

Comment: This is the most relevant example of adding attributes to existing simple-content types: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_extension.asp

Comment: This answer works. Thank you. Accepted. i'm not sure why it works, or to be more specific why each element requires it's own separately declared type. i'll take your word for it that the linked w3schools page relates to my question or your answer.

Comment: @Ian: Are you familiar with object-oriented development? If so, you know that things can be one type, but that type can extend or implement other types. When you define an `<xs:element>` with the `type` attribute, you're saying that "this element is this type". When you define an element with `<xs:complexType>` inside it, you're also saying "this element is this type". When you use both at the same time, you're saying that your element is two different types, and that's only allowed is one is an extension of another, which is why you need the `<xs:extension>` part.

Comment: Of course it's not really like that, which is why you should read up on this stuff, but conceptually it might help you to understand it.

Comment: i am familiar with typed languages. Except i would separate types from rules applied to them. e.g. many values are of the type `integer`, but this one can only be positive, this one can only be greater than 10,000, this one can only be 724 and 863. Conceptually i separate a type from limitations on instances of that type.

Comment: @Ian: Depending on the language, those are either types or restrictions on types. In the case of XSD, a restriction or extension of an existing type defines a new type.